# TWIG: How to parse custom tags?

Tags: twig, symfony, template-engine

In TWIG templating engine, what would be the best way to parse the content like following:

```
[name="tom"]
    Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit amet</strong>, 
    consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
[/name]
```

into something like:

```
<blockquote>
    Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit amet</strong>, 
    consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</blockquote>
```

And also fetch the value of **name** attribute. In the above given example, the value of attribute **name** is **tom**. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe with a filter ? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Comment: You will need to imlement your own [node](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#defining-a-node) to do this

Answer (score 1):

I ended up utilizing the `Twig_SimpleFunction()` method to create a custom TWIG function (extension).

```
/**
 * @var $html STRING FROM THE POST
 * @return $string RETURN AS STRING
 */
public function toBlockQuotedFormat($html) {

    $re = '/(.*?)\[name=(.*?)\]/';
    preg_match_all($re, $html, $matches);

    if(isset($matches[2][0])) {

        $name = $matches[2][0];
        // CONVERT THE NAME-TAG TO BLOCKQUOTE
        $html = str_replace("[name=".$name."]", "<blockquote>", $html);
        $html = str_replace("[/name]", "</blockquote>", $html);
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Then I was able to use `{{ toBlockQuotedFormat(theHtmlVar|nl2br)|raw }}` to parse it to desired `<blockquote></blockquote>` tag. I also have the `$name` value; however on this occasion I did not make use of it other than for `str_replace` function.